# Using my WPF window like a splash window

Tags: wpf

For my WPF application I need a splash window, but I want to 
display some text about initialization process of application,
something like "Read config file", "Reading data base data".
Can I use the standart splash window ?

If not I can use a general WPF window, but I want it to appear and disappear 
slow, like splash window. How can I do this ?
Thanks

Comment: The WPF standard splash screen is a static image, so you can't use that.

Comment: Like @Sami said, you can't use the standard splash window. Your best bet is to create a **borderless** window which *looks like* a splash screen, but with the additional functionality of displaying initialization messages and what not.

Comment: Yes, I agree, but how to make a window to appear and disappear slow

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is a Custom Window as splash screen.
Here is a good post about how to achieve this:

http://www.dontpaniclabs.com/blog/post/2013/11/14/dynamic-splash-screens-in-wpf/

Adding that you can send messages from your MainWindow during loading time regarding any processes taking place. Here's a example in which I wanted to load some data first and make sure they're rendered before the user sees the window:

```
private void _Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        .... some time consuming processes ....

        App.splashScreen.AddMessage("Data Loaded...");
    }
```

And when you are done with everything and you are sure your UI is ready:

```
    private void _Window_ContentRendered(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        App.splashScreen.LoadComplete();
    }
```